# excel process different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Assuming I have an Excel sheet called "Sheet A" with the following columns,
and I also have separate sheets named "Service1," "Service2," and "Service3":

| Process name | service1 | service2 | service3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | V | V |  |
| BBB |  | V |  |
| CCC |  |  | V |
| DDD | V |  |  |

What formulas should I enter in sheets "Service1," "Service2," and "Service3" to achieve the following objectives?

- If the value in the "Service1" column is "V," I want to store the value of the "Process name" column in cell A of the "Service1" sheet.
- If the value in the "Service2" column is "V," I want to store the value of the "Process name" column in cell A of the "Service2" sheet.
- If the value in the "Service3" column is "V," I want to store the value of the "Process name" column in cell A of the "Service3" sheet.

In other words,

sheet Service1 should like this:

| Process name |
| --- |
| AAA |
| DDD |

sheet Service2 should like this:

| Process name |
| --- |
| AAA |
| BBB |

sheet Service3 should like this:

| Process name |
| --- |
| CCC |

I have no idea about this, so I'm seeking help.

Comment: Try using `FILTER`.

Comment: Can u tell me how to do?

Comment: @Arien https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Comment: I would do somewhat i like this : `=FILTER('Sheet A'!A2:A5,XLOOKUP(RIGHT(CELL("filename"),LEN(CELL("filename"))-FIND("]",CELL("filename"))),'Sheet A'!B1:D1,'Sheet A'!B2:D5)="V")` also instead of using multiple sheets use one sheet and a dropdown to change the sheet name and get the output

Comment: try study on https://exceljet.net/functions/filter-function , and share how far your have got ,,